# Unable to view inline images in ExtentReport that was sent to a different email id using JavaMail API?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jakarta-mail

For my selenium web driver testing i am using extent report in my framework, The report is stored in a shared folder in a server. After completion of the test, the report is sent to various email ids as attachment using JAVAMAIL API. Not every one except me , can see the inline image in the report. I dont know how to trouble shoot. Please find the attached code for the email that I have created.
Waiting for a quick response

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class EmailAttachmentSender {

    public static void sendEmailWithAttachments(Map<String, String> map, List<String> attachFiles)
            throws AddressException, MessagingException {
        // sets SMTP server properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", map.get("host"));
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", map.get("port"));
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        //properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","java.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.put("mail.user", map.get("mailFrom"));
        properties.put("mail.password", map.get("password"));

        try
        {
        // creates a new session with an authenticator
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(map.get("mailFrom"), map.get("password"));
            }
        };
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

        // creates a new e-mail message
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(map.get("mailFrom")));


        InternetAddress[] toAddresses = new InternetAddress[map.get("mailTo").split(",").length];
        for (int i =0;i<map.get("mailTo").split(",").length;i++)
        {
            toAddresses[i]=new InternetAddress(map.get("mailTo").split(",")[i]);
        }

        if(map.get("mailTo").split(",").length!=0)
        {
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
        }


        InternetAddress[] ccAddresses = new InternetAddress[map.get("mailCc").split(",").length];

        for (int i =0;i<map.get("mailCc").split(",").length;i++)
        {
            ccAddresses[i]=new InternetAddress(map.get("mailCc").split(",")[i]);
        }

        if(map.get("mailCc").split(",").length!=0)
        {
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, ccAddresses);
        }



        msg.setSubject(map.get("subject"));
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // creates message part
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(map.get("message"), "text/plain");

        // creates multi-part
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // adds attachments
        if (attachFiles != null && attachFiles.size() > 0) {
            for (String filePath : attachFiles) {
                MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                try {
                     //attachPart.attachFile(filePath);
                    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filePath);

                    attachPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));

                    attachPart.setFileName(filePath);



                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
            }
        }

        // sets the multi-part as e-mail's content
        msg.setContent(multipart);

        // sends the e-mail
        Transport.send(msg);

    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(" You might have entered wrong email information in the Configuration.properties file. Please recheck");
    }
    }

    /**
     * Test sending e-mail with attachments
     */
  //public static void main(String[] args) {
        public static void sendEmail(String reportPath) {

       Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
        // SMTP info
        String host = UtilityClass.getPropertyData("host");
        String port = UtilityClass.getPropertyData("port");
        String mailFrom = UtilityClass.getPropertyData("mailFrom");
        String password = UtilityClass.getPropertyData("password");


        map.put("host", host);
        map.put("port", port);
        map.put("mailFrom", mailFrom);
        map.put("password", password);



        // message info
        String mailTo = UtilityClass.getPropertyData("mailTo");
        String mailCc = UtilityClass.getPropertyData("mailCc");
        String subject = UtilityClass.getPropertyData("subject");
        String message = UtilityClass.getPropertyData("message");

        map.put("mailTo", mailTo);
        map.put("mailCc", mailCc);
        map.put("subject", subject);
        map.put("message", message);

        // attachments
       //String attachFile = "E:/LeEco/Automation/Framework_India/LeMall/test-output/ExtentReport/LeMallIndia-PC-16122016_034807.html";
      System.out.println(reportPath);
        String attachFile =  reportPath;
        List<String> attachFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        attachFiles.add(attachFile);

        try {
            if(!map.get("mailTo").equals("")||map.get("mailTo")!=null)
            {
                 sendEmailWithAttachments(map, attachFiles);
                        System.out.println("Email sent.");
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Could not send email.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the attached html file is referencing images that are only on your local disk (either by using explicit "file:" URLs, or by using relative URLs that are relative to where the html file is stored on your local disk), no one else is going to be able to see them.

You either need to put the images on a web server and make sure the html file is referencing them using "http:" URLs for the web server, or you need to package both the html file and the images into a multipart/related MIME part and make sure the html file is referencing the images using a "cid:" URL.

The [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#sendmpr) has more information.

Also, you might want to fix some of these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).